# How to transfer luggage from Paris to London?

Tags: london, paris, luggage-storage, shipping

I live in Paris now and my rent contract is ending this June. Starting from September I will move to London for a long period, so I was wondering if it is possible to leave my stuff in London directly, since in the summer I will be somewhere else.

1) what is the best option to send my luggage from Paris to London (2/3 big suitcases, a printing machine and a box of books)? (e.g. French mail, couriers, ...)

2) is there any place in London where you can leave safely this kind of stuff for a few months for a reasonable price? Of course asking to some friends was already considered ;)

Comment: What do you mean by best? Moreover I fail to see how this question relates to travel since you are moving for long periods of time rather than travelling. Voting to close.

Comment: try sendmybag.com